# get value jtextfield from another class to actionperformed method

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have two class, one is for swing and main class, one is for actionperformed method

```
//class swing
package system;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI{
   JFrame frame = new JFRame("frame");
   JTextField tx = new JTextField(10);
   JButton bt = new JButton("button");

   public void getTx(){
      return tx.getText();
   }

   public void init(){
      frame.setSize(200, 200);
      frame.add(tx);
      frame.add(bt);
      tx.setBounds(20, 20, 140, 50);
      bt.setBounds(20, 100, 120, 40);
      btaddcom.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            control.btclicked(e);
        }
    });
   }

   public GUI(){
      init();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            new GUI().frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

below is my other class

```
package system;
import java.awt;
import java.awt.event.*;

public abstract control implements ActionListener{
    public static void btclicked(ActionEvent e){
         GUI gui = new GUI();
         String txf = gui.getTx();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txf);
    }
}
```

My question is why I cannot get the value from JTextField tx, because it is always blank whenever text I filled it.
Thanks

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making a new instance of the GUI class, so all the fields will be empty/reset.

Here's what you should do:

```
public abstract control implements ActionListener{
    public static void btclicked(ActionEvent e, GUI gui){
        String txf = gui.getTx();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txf);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
btaddcom.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        control.btclicked(e, GUI.this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow I was editing while you wrote that and now it looks like one of us copied each other ._.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer because you are the one with less reputation, and you need more. :-)

Comment: @AshutoshGojiya Much nicer :D - but still won't work, `control.btclicked(e, this);` should be `control.btclicked(e, GUI.this);` ;)

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for fixing the answer from the original suggestion ;)

Comment: Okay maybe it is time to sleep (hate it when this happens)

Comment: Finally worked, with MadProgrammer's method, just made "this" become "GUI.this" and the rest with Ashutosh Gojiya's method

Comment: @AshutoshGojiya `control.btclicked(e, this)` actually means is actually saying "use the instance of the `ActionListener`". when you actually want `GUI.this` - annoying I know

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new instance `GUI`.  This has no relation ship to what is begin displayed on the screen, so any updates you try to make to it won't be reflected on the screen...

Instead, you should be passing either some kind of model (preferrabbly) or a reference to the `GUI` or `JTextField`.

Something more like...

```
public abstract control implements ActionListener{
    public static void btclicked(ActionEvent e, GUI gui){
         String txf = gui.getTx();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txf);
    }
}
```

For example.

Personally, I prefer to provide a model of some kind, as it prevent exposing additional content to the caller, as your `btclicked` method now has full control over your `GUI` class, which you may not want

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if this was solved if I read the comments correctly.  But just in case, there's also a basic syntax error.  Your getTx() method is returning a string but you have it listed as void.  I'm sure this was caught right away but I figure it doesn't hurt to point it out just in case.  Cheers.

```
public String getTx(){
    return tx.getText();
}
```